# Solve this integral for free WiFi

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I saw this today, I checked in Mathematica and the integral comes out to $\pi$, but I have no idea how to solve it.

> FREE Wi-Fi: The Wi-Fi password is the first $10$ digits of the answer.
>   $$\int_{-2}^2\left(x^3\cos\frac x2+\frac12\right)\sqrt{4-x^2}\ dx$$

[image]

Comment: Motivation: think about even and odd functions whenever you see the integral from some $-a$ to $a$.

Comment: So not only do you have to do the integral to get $\pi$, you have to know $10$ digits of it.  Or at least be able to find those $10$ digits on your laptop/phone without using Wifi.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The integrand is the sum of an odd and even function, and only the latter contributes, so it's $\int_0^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$. This is a quarter of the area of a radius-$2$ circle, i.e. $\pi$.

Answer (score 12):

We have that
$$\int_{-2}^2 x^3 \cos\frac x2 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx =0$$
since the integrand is point symmetric in the origin.
Since $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ on $[-2;2]$ is the formula for the upper part of a circle we find that
$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx=\frac 12 \pi r^2=\frac 12 \pi 2^2=2\pi$$
So the whole integral is:
$$\int_{-2}^2(x^3\cos \frac x2 +\frac 12 )\sqrt{4-x^2} dx=\int_{-2}^2 x^3 \cos\frac x2 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx+\frac 12\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx=0+\frac 12 2\pi=\pi$$