# Solve the integral, perhaps by parts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluate the following integral $$\int\left(\operatorname{cos}\frac{x}{2}\cdot x^3+\frac12\right)\sqrt{4-x^2}\:\:dx$$

My work: I thought if doing it by integration by parts. So I evaluated some integrals individually. $$\int\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\dfrac{x\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}+2\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)+c$$ and $$\int \left(\operatorname{cos}\frac{x}{2}\cdot x^3+\frac12\right)dx=16\left(\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{x^3}{8}-3x\right)+\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{3x^2}{4}-6\right)\right)+\dfrac{x}{2}+c$$ What to do now, I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

IMO the answer is $$\dfrac{x\sqrt{4-x^2}+4\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{4}+c$$ Can anybody review$?$

Comment: Is this the famous wi-fi integral meme (without the bounds)?

Comment: The original question had bounds $-2,2$

Comment: @Zacky what is wi fi integral

Comment: you must use integration by parts to eliminate the factor $ x^3 $

Comment: [Wi-Fi integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427744/515527). Also you will definitely need some weird special functions perhaps to solve the indefinite integral, so better keep the bounds.

Comment: With symmetric bounds you can remove most of it by symmetry. I don't think an elementary antiderivative exists.

Comment: The bounds, IMO, are actually important as in, they help us to remove the trigonometric functions ($x^3\cos x/2$) part. I could replace that with any crazy odd function like $$\frac {x^2(\arctan x)^2(x-\sin x)}{\cos^{2020}x\ln|x|}$$ and still keep the same answer for the definite integral.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is the famous wifi integral

Comment: OP asks for the indefinite integral, while the Wifi integral is specifically over a symmetric interval, which is also the trick to that computation.

Comment: @Lorago still he accepted my answer